# JPA annotations and SQL tables

Tags: java, sql, jpa, entity

I just have quick Question. If I had an sql script like this:

```
create table person(
    phoneNumber int
    name varchar(100) not null
    primary key(phoneNumber, name)
);
```

How would I set up the Entity Class for this in Java using JPA Annotations?

I have this so far:

```
@Entity
public class Person {


    @Column(name="phoneNumber")
    public int phoneNumber;


    @Column(name="name" length=255)
    public String name;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

- you'll need `@Table("person")` on the class
- you'll need `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddableId` to specify the primary key.  Check the documentations of those for how exactly to achieve it. `@IdClass` is a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/cmp30cfg001.htm

Basically, what you have is a composite primary key. What you'll end up with is a MemberOFPK class that encapsulates the fields of the primary key, and then your MemberOf class will have either an EmbeddedID or two @ID classes depending on whether you make the primary key class embeddable or not.